# Issue with Chromadb onnxruntime

Tags: python, langchain, onnxruntime, chromadb

So, I'm building an application that uses lang chain's chromadb for vector storage and I'm extracting those vectors from the db. I'm not facing any trouble in coding, I was running this code in a VM (windows 11 pro) with python version 3.11.2. Now, I've shared the code with my teammates and they're facing an error that says "Onnxruntime is not found, use pip install onnxruntime to install it", but it is already installed when I did `pip install chromadb`, but again I tried uninstalling and installing onnxruntime multiple time, every time it is installing successfully and path is also set correct, but the system always throws the same error that onnxruntime is not found. I've been banging my head for last three days on why this is happening, I've did freeze command from the working system and installed that, same OS as working system, same python version as working version. Is there any solution to this problem? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try below steps

```
c:\yourprojectdirectory> conda create --prefix ./you_env_name python=3.11

c:\yourprojectdirectory> conda activate "your new env path"
```

After this

```
pip install chromadb
```

if still you face issue, you can try below as well

```
pip install onnxruntime
```

Answer (score -1):

Try installing [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170). This helped me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35409775)

Comment: Installing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable fixed the issue with onnxruntime. Why did you delete my reply with the solution?